spring-data-elasticsearch elasticsearch opensearch spring boot upgrade
I am in process to upgrade sprint boot from 2.7.16 to to 3.2.4
As part of it I upgraded spring-data-elasticsearch, elasticsearch as below
spring-data-elasticsearch from 4.3.3 to 5.1.4,
elasticsearch from 7.13.4 to 7.17.13,
lucene 8.11.1
The connection is to aws opensearch.
The application was able to come up with previous versions but with latest, I am getting error: Elasticsearch version 6 or more is required.
Google search says, versions are not compatible with opensearch.
Spring data elasticsearch version compatibility matrix https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/elasticsearch/reference/elasticsearch/versions.html suggest to have below
spring-data-elasticsearch: 5.2.x,
elasticsearch: 8.11.4,
spring framework: 6.1.x
Question: with above versions, will it able to bring the app up with connection to opensearch ?
I am still getting errors while upgrading various versions(lucene, rest-client etc) so before I spend more time I want to make sure the connection to opensearch is possible.

Why not using https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch since you're connecting to OpenSearch?

Thank you for reply @Val. I was just checking it from another post when you replied. But is it possible with dependencies I asked ? to not worry about apache license and not updating code to have opensearch imports going.

You need to check that with the people who built spring-data-opensearch.

Really appreciate the reply @Elastic/Val . It really helped and fixed my issue.

Thank you @P.J.Meisch for reply. I went through how you guys came about separate repo for spring-data-opensearch and discussion you had & meetings with various stack holders during summer of '22.  Amazing. Appreciate it.
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1918
https://github.com/opensearch-project/spring-data-opensearch/issues/89
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-elasticsearch/issues/1770

@Val's comment is the answer.Please refer the repo.
